# Mongoose find by ID and then find specific ID inside an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that looks like this

[image]

How can I perform a query that search for the ID and then from the result, I wanna perform another query for the specific ID in the comments array?

I tried this but this is causing an error

```
try {
      TourDB.Tour.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.tourId, comments._id: req.body.commentId }, { $inc: { comments.$.likes : 1}}).exec(async (err, docs) => {
         if (!err) {
            return res.status(200).send(docs);
         } else {
            return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage: `An error occured: ${err}` });
         }
      });
   } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage: `An error occured: ${err}` });
   }
```

I want to find a specific comment by ID within a document and update the likes by one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:
You missed the quotes ""

```
try {
      const tour = await TourDB.Tour.findOneAndUpdate(
         { _id: req.body.tourId, 'comments._id': req.body.commentId },
         { $inc: { 'comments.$.likes': 1 } }
      ).exec();
      res.status(200).send(tour);
   } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage: `An error occured: ${err}` });
}
```